# I have not set a character limit on a field in Craft CMS but can't save entry because content is too long?

Tags: craftcms

I have a rich text field in Craft CMS. I have not set a character limit on it but when saving 100 paragraphs I am unable to save because "entry content is too long".

Why am I getting this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you are hitting a storage limit for the field in the database? If I look at a rich text field (in my case, Redactor), under the Advanced option I can change the **Column Type** from text (~64KB) to mediumtext (~16MB).

[image: Screenshot of advanced options for Redactor field]

Personally, I have always found text plenty, but then I don't think I've ever tried to save a text block containing 100 paragraphs. Just a bit more information: [Understanding Storage Sizes for MySQL TEXT Data Types](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/understanding-strorage-sizes-for-mysql-text-data-types/)